# Proving an extension to nesbitts inequality: $\frac a{b+c}+\frac b{c+a}+\frac c{a+b}\lt 2$

Tags: inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Prove that $$\frac a{b+c}+\frac b{c+a}+\frac c{a+b}\lt 2$$ given that $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle.

I know that the above is $\ge \frac32$ but how will you prove the above?

I know this might sound a bit basic but please help.

Comment: Even without the substitution it is obvious. Let $a$ be the largest side. Then the first term is less than $1$ and if we replace $a$ by $b$ and $c$ in the denominators of two other terms, increasing each of them, they'll add up to $1$.

Comment: I've seen this too late, so, @fedja, by the triangle inequality $a\lt b+c\implies\frac{a}{b+c}\lt 1$ and then $\frac{b+c}{2a}\leqslant\frac{2a}{2a}=1$ if, as you said, $a$ is the greatest, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the substitution $a = x+y, b = y+z, c = z+x$.

**Hint:** $a + b > x+y+z, b+c > x+y+z, c+a > x+y+z$.

Answer (score 1):

Building on an additional answer, you need to prove that in the process of making substitutions $a = x + y$, $b = y + z$, $c = z + x$ that you can do so using strictly positive $x,y,z$.  This will require using properties of a triangle, because in general solving the above system $x,y,z$ for general $a,b,c$ (not sides of a triangle) can give either $x,y$ or $z$ negative.  If you can ensure that $x,y,z$ are all positive then the rest should be trivial as indicated by the earlier hints.  As a further hint, here are the inverse substitutions that give you $x,y,z$:

$$x = (a-b+c)/2$$
$$y = (a+b-c)/2$$
$$z = (-a+b+c)/2$$

Comment: The existence of $x, y, z$ also follows from considering the incircle ,where the lengths are the external tangents, hence positive.

Answer (score 1):

Because $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}<\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{a+b+c}=2$$