# for triamgle $ABC$ prove that $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b} <2$

Tags: inequality

> Let   $ a,b,c$ be lengths of sides  triangle $ ABC$.
>   Prove that:
>   $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b} <2$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ For a $\triangle $ with sides $a,b,c$

$a+b>c$ and $b+c>a$ and $a+b>c$

Now let $x=a+b-c>0$ and $y=b+c-a>0$ and $z=c+a-b>0$

So $\displaystyle 2a=x+z$ and $2b=x+y$ and $2c=y+z$

So equality convert into $$\frac{x+z}{x+2y+z}+\frac{x+y}{x+y+2z}+\frac{y+z}{2x+y+z}<2$$

How can i solve above inequality, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Now substitute the values of x, y, z and you will get the answer.

Comment: This was a famous International Olympiad problem....the whole question was to prove that $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}$ is bounded between $2$ and $\frac 32$...For the $\frac 32$ part check out Nesbitt's Inequality-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality .....Thanks and hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry we may assume that $a\leq b\leq c$ . In that case

$\frac {a}{a+b}+\frac {b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\leq \frac{a}{a+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}+\frac {c}{a+b}=1+\frac{c}{a+b}$

but $1+\frac {c}{a+b}<2$

so $\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}<2$

Comment: The question is a duplicate so we already have answers for this. Look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903775/triangle-inequality-sum-textcyc-fracabc2

Comment: We have $\frac{a}{a+b}\ge \frac{a}{a+c}$, because $b\le c$. You made a mistake.