# Prove the following triangle related inequality

Tags: inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> Prove that $\dfrac32\leq \dfrac{a}{b+c}+\dfrac{b}{a+c}+\dfrac{c}{a+b} < 2.$ where $a$ ,$b$ ,$c$ are sides of Triangle

I tried using sine rule which makes up the the expression $\sum \dfrac{\sin{A}}{\sin{B}+\sin{C}}$. Now i dont how to find the range of $\sum \dfrac{\sin{A}}{\sin{B}+\sin{C}}$. Any ideas(hint) or solution would be really appreciated.

Comment: The one part is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality

Comment: Oh really thanks i find the proof by am gm easy and nice enough. Do u also have proof for the second part.

Comment: For the second part i would assume w.l.o.g. the relation $a\ge b\ge c=1$, then use variables $s,t$ with $s,t\ge 0$, $b=1+s$, $a=b+t=1+s+t$, so that $1+s+t=a< b+c=1+1+s$. The expression depends on two variables. After playing around i noted that for $c\to 0$ we get in the limit $a/b+b/a  \le 2$, well...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inequality based on triangle: $\frac{3}{2}\le\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}<2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950188/inequality-based-on-triangle-frac32-le-fracabc-fracbca-fracc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, you can use Nesbitt's inequality (which is ultimately an application of the Arithmetic-Geometric mean inequality) for the lower bound.

For the upper bound, note that since $a < b+c$, we have $\frac{a}{b+c} < \frac{a+a}{b+c+a} = \frac{2a}{a+b+c}$. Now apply similar inequalities to the other terms and sum them.

Comment: If $0<u<v$ then $\frac{u}{v} < \frac{u+a}{v+a}$ for $a>0$ (just cross multiply).

Answer (score 0):

Making $b = x a$ and $c=y a$ the conditions read

$$
\frac 32\le\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{x}{1+y}+\frac{y}{1+x}\le 2 \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ x + y\ge 1
$$

so making the lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,\lambda) = \frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{x}{1+y}+\frac{y}{1+x}+\lambda(x+y-1)
$$

We have two stationary points. One at $x^*=1, y^* = 1$ corresponding to a minimum $(\frac 32)$ and $x^* = \frac 12, y^* = \frac 12$ corresponding to a maximum $\frac 53$ so we have

$$
\frac 32\le \frac 32\le \frac 53\le 2
$$

Comment: I think you mean $x+y>1$.

Comment: @J.G. Of course you are right! Thanks.

Comment: In particular, we use $>$ instead of $\ge$ to exclude degenerate triangles.

Comment: I agree but the limit values in this case, are at degenerate triangles with null area.